# BASH - curl command not work into loop with for

Tags: bash

i need check status of some link listen in a file called `paths.txt`, i have write a simple `for` loop but not work

```
for LINK in $(cat paths.txt)
do
  CURL="$(curl -I $LINK 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2)"
  if [ "${CURL}" = "200" ]
  then
    echo ${LINK} >> true.txt
  else
    echo ${LINK} >> false.txt
  fi
done
```

If i launch the `curl` command from terminal i read the right status, instead if i make an echo of `CURL` variable i not have any output

Comment: instead of `CURL="$(curl -I $LINK 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2)"`, do `echo $LINK`. Do you get the proper content of your file ?

Comment: yes, i have tried and work, i have insert `echo -e "\n$LINK\n"` and show correctly all link sepatared by line

Comment: are there any spaces or special characters (like `*` or `?`) in the URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the script like this: `bash -x myscript` and watch the executed commands.

Comment: i have found a `\r` at the end of any link, i have correct the file format and now works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: This isn't really an answer; it's a general comment that can direct one to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

don't use **cat** in bash scripts, because is bad practice and can be problems with big files.

```
SCRIPTDIR=`dirname -- "$0"`
for siteUrl in $( < "$SCRIPTDIR/paths.txt")
do
    if [[ -z "$siteUrl" ]]; then break; fi
    if [[ "$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}\n" --silent --output /dev/null ${siteUrl} )" = "200" ]];  then
        echo ${siteUrl} >> true.txt
    else
        echo ${siteUrl} >> false.txt
    fi
done
```